# Web user control usage

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, webusercontrol

Is there a simple way to determine where web user controls (wuc) are used in a solution?

I'm trying to get an overview of what's going on in a rather big applications, where I have a large number of wuc's, used both in aspx and nested in other wuc's.

Any suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: are you talking about .ascx files?

Comment: Yes, sorry: .ascx files.

Answer (score 2):

In the .cs file right click on the class name and click on "Find Usages".

This should find all designer files of other controls / pages that use that particular control.

Comment: I tried that: It seems to give me an incorrect listing, as those places where the controls is not referenced in the code-behind class it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ReSharper 6, then right click on the user control .ascx name in the Solution Explorer and click on "Find Usages" (Alt+F7) or "Find Usages Advanced...".

ReSharper should show you where the user control is being used in the entire solution

Answer (score 0):

Well a basic solution would be to do a search of the entire solution for ".ascx"